# Running SSH commands from an android application over Wi-Fi

Tags: android, ssh, jsch

I am completely new to android development. I am looking for a way to execute ssh commands from an android application which will be used on a tablet in future. In particular i need to execute 4 ssh commands to 4 separate servers over wifi. I have come across jsch over some posts. Can someone guide me to some good examples or tutorials for this? Also will it be possible to completely test this functionality on the eclipse android emulator using my laptops wifi connection? I don't have access to an android device as of now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library called CkSsh.

[Getting Started Android](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

[Library Documentation](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/javaCkSshRef.html)

[Android CkSsh Example](http://www.example-code.com/android/ssh_remote_command.asp)

For testing use Android Emulator or [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)